# How to STOP iOS Safari web page from loading cached pages after adding to home screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, web-applications, safari

I have added a website to the iOS home screen. If a load open the website from the iOS home screen, it seem to be always loading a cached page. Even if I updated the page or delete the page entirely, it still load the original version.

It will load the updated page if I open the site directly from iOS Safari instead of clicking the icon on the home screen.

The site is hosted on Apache running Ubuntu 11.10.

I have added following inside

and added

in attempt to force it to load the updated page.

I have also tried clear the cache and cookie and history from iOS Safari setting and also rebooted the ipad and nothing seem to work.

Please help~!

Comment: Could you use `window.location.reload(true)`?

Comment: Could you suggest where I should put it to make it load just once automatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, though it will result in double-loading of your page in instances where it is *not* initially loaded from a cached copy.

```
<script>
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf('rnd=') == -1) {
        url = (url.indexOf("?") == -1 ? url + "?rnd=" : url + "&rnd=") + Math.random();
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

So basically you would add `http://mysite.com/myCoolPage.html` to the iOS home screen, and then whenever the page is loaded in the browser it will redirect to `http://mysite.com/myCoolPage.html?rnd=xxxxxxx`, effectively preventing it from being cached.

Comment: Thanks for the script, it really added the random number it should but for some reason, ios safari still displaying the old page if I click it from ios Home screen @_@

Comment: In the end, I am serving the same static pages on a Rails App and it seem to work.